# Dynamically generate a function in JavaScript depending on input parameters

Tags: javascript, optimization, functional-programming, dynamically-generated

I have a cost function that is supposed to output a cost depending on the parameters of an user and an object. 
As a simple but unrealistic example, let us consider:

```
// example of input user
let user1 = {
  access: [true, false], 
  utility: [2, 5]
};
// example of input object
let object1 = {type: 0, cost: 15};

// static vertions of the cost function
const costFunction = (user, object) => {
  switch (object.type){
    case 0:
      if(user.access[0]){
        return object.cost * user.utility[0];
      }else{
        return Infinity;
      };
    case 1:
      if(user.access[1]){
        return object.cost * user.utility[1];
      }else{
        return Infinity;
      };
  };
};

costFunction(user1, object1)    // sould return 2*15 = 30
```

However, in an algorithms I have to call this function a very large number of times with the same user but with different obejcts. So, I would like to be able to process the user's parameters only once and to dynamically generate a user-adapted cost function as following:

```
// dynamically generated a user-adapted const function
const costFunctionGenerator = (user) => {
    ... some code ... 
    const costFunction = (object) => {
        ... some code ...
    };
    return costFunction;
};

const user1CostFunction = costFunctionGenerator(user1)
```

Such that, `user1CostFunction` would be equal to

```
const user1CostFunction  = (object) => {
   switch (object.type){
      case 0:
         return object.cost * 2;
      case 1:
         return Infinity;
   }
}
```

What happends is that we droped the `if` conditions that comes from the user's parameters `user1.access`and also we converted links from `user1.utility` to direct float elements in the `user1CostFunction`.

My problem is that I have no idea how to implement the function `costFunctionGenerator`.

Comment: drop the switch and replace all [0] and [1] indexes with object.type

Comment: I believe that, what OP has shown is just a plain demonstration of the problem,  not actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the pattern you're looking for is called currying a function.

In pre-es6 Javascript creating curried functions was a little bit clunky, but with the arrival of the arrow functions syntax is a lot nicer. Basically, the only thing you need to do is change your signature to:

```
const costFunctionCurried = (user) => (object) => {
  switch (object.type){
    case 0:
      if(user.access[0]){
        return object.cost * user.utility[0];
      }else{
        return Infinity;
      };
    case 1:
      if(user.access[1]){
        return object.cost * user.utility[1];
      }else{
        return Infinity;
      };
  };
};
```

But how does it work? When you call `costFunctionCurried` first time it *fixes*
all places where variable *user* is called and returns new lambda, which expects only object to be passed:

```
costFunctionCurried(user1)(object1) //you can call it inline

//or you can assign your function to a variable for reuse
const fixedUserCostFunction = costFunctionCurried(user1) 

fixedUserCostFunction(object1)
fixedUserCostFunction(object2) //etc.
```

I created a [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/54jvws6uad/2) to test if the curried version gives any performance benefit and indeed it performs faster.

Comment: Currying would give a true performance advantage if any of the computations would be shared.

Comment: On my PC benchmark shows that uncurried version on chrome is 90.48% slower, so I guess it still gives you some benefit.